# Win Server 2008 Exchange Management Console

Tags: windows-server-2008, email, exchange, mail-forwarding

How do I get distribution lists to FWD to another alias via the Exchange Management Console?

Comment: I don't think you can. What are you trying to do? Do you want a recipient who is not a member of the DG to receive a copy of all emails sent to the DG?

Comment: @DanBig - DG's are already mail enabled. Also, there are no Delivery Options that I'm aware of on a DG.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, i just looked at it.

Comment: I would like to forward a companies DL list which is on a different domain and set a rule that Forwards it to another alias on a different domain. Example: TechTeam@domain1.com FWD TechTeam@domain2.com

Comment: You could create a contact in AD for TechTeam@domain2.com and add the contact to the distribution list.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Contact in Exchange for the external recipient. Add the Contact as a member of the Distribution Group. Done.

Comment: You-da-man Joe.

Comment: Glad to help...